# Allowable surface patches

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]
I’m studying Differential Geometry from Pressley’s book. In this theorem, how does f being a homeomorphism imply the existence of the function F which is smooth, bijective whose inverse is also smooth? How does one arrive at this?